# R ggplot : several scatter distributions + average line by group (time series plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table  with blood sample data collected over 3 period of times (Albumin1, Albumin2,Albumin3). Each sample belongs to a group (placebo vs. test, i.e. 1 or 2 in the table). The table looks like this ('File1'):

| Date1 | Albumin1 | Date2 | Albumin2 | Date3 | Albumine3 | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-11-21 | 21 | 06-12-21 | 21 | 08-03-22 | 28 | 1 |
| 26-11-21 | 19 | 16-12-21 | 23 | 07-03-22 | 26 | 2 |
| 26-11-21 | 31 | 16-12-21 | 24 | 08-03-22 | 29 | 2 |
| 27-11-21 | 31 | 16-12-21 | 23 | 09-03-22 | 26 | 2 |
| 26-11-21 | 32 | 16-12-21 | 25 | 08-03-22 | 28 | 1 |

From this I would like to draw a time series plot like this, with colours per group and different symbols for the 3 series (as they can overlap) and with the average value for each group plotted with a line over time:

[image]

I assume that the first step involves the calculation of the means for each group and period of time. So I created a table ('Table2') summarising the data like this:

| Date_mean | Albumin_mean | Albumin_number | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26-11-21 | 20 | 1 | 1 |
| 26-11-21 | 30 | 2 | 2 |
| 26-11-21 | 21 | 3 | 1 |
| 30-11-21 | 26 | 1 | 2 |
| 27-11-21 | 27 | 2 | 1 |
| 27-11-21 | 28 | 3 | 2 |

Here is the first attempt of ggplot code:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = Table1 , aes(x = as.Date(Date1,format=("%d-%m-%y")), aes(y=Albumin1), aes(colour = factor(Group)))+ 
  geom_line(data = Table2,  aes(x = as.Date(Date_mean,format=("%d-%m-%y")), y=Albumin_mean))
```

I guess I have to add extra "geom_point()" for the 2 other scatter distributions, but I am stuck with the colours and symbols.

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Falco. I'm sure we can help you easily if you supply the data in a reproducible format where we can copy and paste it into our consoles. You are less likely to get help by posting an image of your data, unless some kind soul transcribes it from the _picture_ of your data. You may find `dput(Table1)` and `dput(Table2)` useful in this respect. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron, I edited my post to take this into consideration.

Comment: You may want this kind of graph but a more scientific way to present these data will be to present as boxplots on 3 dates, grouped by group1or2. Or one can show connected mean points with SD or SE bars. Then there will be no need to show individual data points. If one has to show individual data points, ideally corresponding points on 3 dates should also be connected (and not just connected mean points).

Comment: Thank you @rnso Actually I would like to keep the points as they have different dates on the x-axis (with a boxplot I could see the distribution but not the differences in dates).

Comment: I meant one boxplot per group per date.

Comment: My graph format is shown in the answer to this question, which I have posted for the problem I encountered in Python while trying to plot boxplots with dates and groups. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73259835/date-formatting-on-x-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: Boxplots do not come properly for current data sample since there is 1 or very few data points for many dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to get data in this format to plot nicely, so your first step should be to get your data into *tidy* format. This means each row should be an observation, and each column should be a variable. The date should also be in an actual `Date` format, rather than a string representation.

The following shows how we can get your table into this format:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tidy_data <- Table1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Group, names_pattern = "(.*)(\\d)", 
               names_to = c('.value', "Series")) %>%
  group_by(Series) %>%
  mutate(Date  = lubridate::dmy(Date),
         Group = factor(Group))
```

We can see that we now have a single column for Albumin, a single column for Date, and columns to indicate which series and which group each measurement belongs to:

```
tidy_data
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   Series [3]
#>    Group Series Date       Albumin
#>    <fct> <chr>  <date>       <int>
#>  1 1     1      2021-11-20      21
#>  2 1     2      2021-12-06      21
#>  3 1     3      2022-03-08      28
#>  4 2     1      2021-11-26      19
#>  5 2     2      2021-12-16      23
#>  6 2     3      2022-03-07      26
#>  7 2     1      2021-11-26      31
#>  8 2     2      2021-12-16      24
#>  9 2     3      2022-03-08      29
#> 10 2     1      2021-11-27      31
#> 11 2     2      2021-12-16      23
#> 12 2     3      2022-03-09      26
#> 13 1     1      2021-11-26      32
#> 14 1     2      2021-12-16      25
#> 15 1     3      2022-03-08      28
```

We can similarly make a tidy summary for each group / series combination like so:

```r
summary_data <- tidy_data %>% 
  group_by(Series) %>%
  mutate(Date = mean(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Group, Date) %>%
  summarize(Albumin = mean(Albumin))

summary_data
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   Group [2]
#>   Group Date       Albumin
#>   <fct> <date>       <dbl>
#> 1 1     2021-11-25    26.5
#> 2 1     2021-12-14    23  
#> 3 1     2022-03-08    28  
#> 4 2     2021-11-25    27  
#> 5 2     2021-12-14    23.3
#> 6 2     2022-03-08    27
```

Now the plotting code itself is relatively straightforward:

```r
ggplot(tidy_data, aes(Date, Albumin, color = Group)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Series), size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = summary_data) +
  geom_point(data = summary_data) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
Table1 <- structure(list(Date1 = c("20-11-21", "26-11-21", "26-11-21", 
"27-11-21", "26-11-21"), Albumin1 = c(21L, 19L, 31L, 31L, 32L
), Date2 = c("06-12-21", "16-12-21", "16-12-21", "16-12-21", 
"16-12-21"), Albumin2 = c(21L, 23L, 24L, 23L, 25L), Date3 = c("08-03-22", 
"07-03-22", "08-03-22", "09-03-22", "08-03-22"), Albumin3 = c(28L, 
26L, 29L, 26L, 28L), Group = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```