# Date formatting on x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, format

I have following data:

```
    ID      Date  Chemical  Group
0    6  06-12-21        21      1
1   12  07-03-22        26      2
2   11  08-03-22        28      1
3   13  08-03-22        29      2
4   15  08-03-22        28      1
5   14  09-03-22        26      2
6    7  16-12-21        23      2
7    8  16-12-21        24      2
8    9  16-12-21        23      2
9   10  16-12-21        25      1
10   1  20-11-21        21      1
11   2  26-11-21        19      2
12   3  26-11-21        31      2
13   5  26-11-21        32      1
14   4  27-11-21        31      2
```

I set the format for date column, sort on it and print it:

```
maindf['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(maindf['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
maindf.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)
print(maindf)
```

Dates are properly recognised:

```
    ID       Date  Chemical  Group
10   1 2021-11-20        21      1
11   2 2021-11-26        19      2
12   3 2021-11-26        31      2
13   5 2021-11-26        32      1
14   4 2021-11-27        31      2
0    6 2021-12-06        21      1
6    7 2021-12-16        23      2
7    8 2021-12-16        24      2
8    9 2021-12-16        23      2
9   10 2021-12-16        25      1
1   12 2022-03-07        26      2
2   11 2022-03-08        28      1
3   13 2022-03-08        29      2
4   15 2022-03-08        28      1
5   14 2022-03-09        26      2
```

I draw boxplots:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(data=maindf, x='Date', y='Chemical', hue='Group')
plt.xticks(rotation=20)
plt.show()
```

I get following graph:

[image]

I see that although the dates are correct here, the times (hours, minutes, seconds) are also shown on x-axis with all these set as 0. I want to remove these so I set format for date on x-axis and then again display the graph:

```
sns.boxplot(data=maindf, x='Date', y='Chemical', hue='Group')
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
dtFmt = DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y') # define the formatting
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dtFmt) 
plt.xticks(rotation=20)
plt.show()
```

Now I get following graph:

[image]

I find that the dates on x-axis are all wrong. They start from 1-1-1970! Where is the problem and how can it be corrected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way seaborn handles the trailing zeros, think this is not getting set properly.
One way to fix it is to use `strftime()` AFTER you have sorted the data to change the datetime back to string like this...

```
maindf['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(maindf['Date'])
maindf.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)
maindf['Date'] = maindf['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') ## Change to format you need
sns.boxplot(data=maindf, x='Date', y='Chemical', hue='Group')
plt.xticks(rotation=40)
plt.show()
```

The other option is to use get & set `xticklabels()` by removing the everything from `T` onwards, so that you see the right format.

```
maindf['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(maindf['Date'])
maindf.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)
sns.boxplot(data=maindf, x='Date', y='Chemical', hue='Group')
plt.gca().set_xticklabels([date_text.get_text().split("T")[0] for date_text in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()])
plt.xticks(rotation=40)
plt.show()
```

Both would give you the below date format...

[image]

Comment: Very good answer with 2 options.

Comment: The problem is that x-axis shows equidistant entries, while dates are not equidistant.

Comment: The dates are aligned to each of the boxplot, so each tick (and corresponding box) have one of the 8 dates that you have provided. If you run your original code, it will also have the same 8 dates. My understanding was that you were not ok with the format, but data was correct (20-Nov-21 to 9-Mar-22). If we overwrite the dates, they will be incorrect as the dates will not match with the boxes. While maybe possible to assign equi-distant dates, it may not be the right thing to do. Perhaps you need to clarify the question  on what you need

Comment: My current question is for date format on x-axis, for which you have provided an answer. Maybe I will post another question.

Comment: I have posted a separate question on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73266348/date-ticks-not-separated-properly-on-x-axis